# Problema com String no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou fazendo uma condição pra adicionar um campo no banco, ou seja, só vai adicionar caso a condição seja igual a 0. O problema é que na minha instrução `execute immediate` ele fala que a palavra PRIMARIO é inválido. Isso ocorre porque deveria estar com aspas simples('') mas como posso tratar isso já que toda a query já está com aspas ? Detalhe: Se for um número funciona já que o mesmo não precisa de aspas.

```
declare 
 col_count  integer;
begin 
 select count(*)
   into col_count
 from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'BALANCA'
 and column_name = 'TIPO';
 if col_count = 0 then
    execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE BALANCA ADD TIPO varchar2(255 char) default PRIMARIO not null';
    commit;
 end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> execute immediate 'ALTER TABLE BALANCA ADD TIPO varchar2(255 char) default PRIMARIO not null';

Tenta por duas aspas, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Não estou com Oracle na minha máquina, mas funciona igual no Oracle!)

Comment: E o perguntador some ...